# Visualize/put multiple graphs in one figure/graph

Tags: matlab

I have 5 figures/graphs that I would like combine into one plot/figure in order to compare them and visualize the differences. Each graph has 3 lines in different colors, and the length of the graphs differs as well. As you already have figured out; combining them will look like a disaster and you will not even be able to see to which of these graphs the lines belongs to.

I would need some help here, and maybe an example as I am a novice user in MATLAB. Is it possible to combine them in a easy and nice looking way?

Comment: Can you at least show as the graphs?

Answer (score 2):

Try [subplot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/create-graph-with-subplots.html). You can easily use that. How fancy/understandable you can do depends on your skills

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if I understand your problem, but I think `subplot` might do what you are looking for. Here is an example of how to create plots for `y=x`, `y=x^2`, `y=x^3`, `y=x^4`, and `y=x^5` in a single figure using subplot.

```
x = linspace(0,10,100) ; 
y1 = x ; 
y2 = x.^2 ;
y3 = x.^3 ;
y4 = x.^4 ;
y5 = x.^5 ;

subplot(2,3,1) ; plot(x,y1) ;
subplot(2,3,2) ; plot(x,y2) ;
subplot(2,3,3) ; plot(x,y3) ;
subplot(2,3,4) ; plot(x,y4) ;
subplot(2,3,5) ; plot(x,y5) ;
```

The first 2 inputs create a grid (each position on the grid can receive 1 plot), and the third input determines where the current plot will be placed.